# Maven-resource-plugin builds invalid xml after filtering

Tags: xml, maven, resources, escaping, filtering

I have a lot of resource files in a java project. Many of them duplicate some values. I decided to move all of the values to an **application.properties** file and propagate them to other files during project build using [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) like it's shown below:

```
<build>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties
            </filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
<build/>
```

A content of the **application.properties** file is below:

```
email.regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$

# other properties
```

For example, let's assume that I use `email.regexp` property in a **MyXML.xml** file like it's shown below:

```
<composite-id name="id" class="UserID">
    <key-property name="email">
        <column name="email" check="email ~ $$${email.regexp}$$"/>
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
<!--other content-->
```

As you could notice, the `email.regexp` contains an ampersand character. It is one of [the characters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_xml_escape.html) to be escaped in an *.xml* file.

### The question

1. How to configure [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to escape [the characters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_xml_escape.html)  in *.xml* resource files during filtering?
2. If the [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) is not the right place to manage build properies, what tool should I use instead?

After executing `mvn package` , the content of **MyXML.xml** is:

### Excpected result

```
<composite-id name="id" class="UserID">
    <key-property name="email">
        <column name="email" check="email ~ $$^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;&apos;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$$$"/>
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
<!--other content-->
```

### Actual result

```
<composite-id name="id" class="UserID">
    <key-property name="email">
        <column name="email" check="email ~ $$^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$$$"/>
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
<!--other content-->
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to use [custom filters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/custom-resource-filters.html).
However, I suppose that the resource plugin is smart enough to recognize one of the most popular formats and apply escaping.